# UIWebView:s viewPrintFormatter() returning... nothing?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uikit

**TL;DR:** why isn't UIWebView:s `viewPrintFormatter()` giving me anything to print?

---

I'm currently trying to print the contents of a UIWebView. I found some examples and ended up with this code:

```swift
let printInteractionController: UIPrintInteractionController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
let printInfo: UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()

printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
printInfo.jobName = self.webView.request!.url!.absoluteString
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfo.Orientation.portrait
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfo.Duplex.longEdge

printInteractionController.printInfo = printInfo
printInteractionController.printFormatter = self.webView.viewPrintFormatter()

printInteractionController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

This code runs perfectly and starts the printing controller as expected.
The page preview is completely blank (gray) however:

[image: UIPrintInteractionController with blank preview page]

If i `dump(self.webView.viewPrintFormatter()` or check `print(self.webView.viewPrintFormatter().numberOfPages)` it seems that the return formatter is empty.

The UIWebView is most certainly not empty.

I've tried with multiple different webpages besides the one I'm interested in printing, getting the same results which ever page I try.

**So, why isn't UIWebView:s `viewPrintFormatter()` giving me anything to print?**

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try using WKWebView it works for me also UIWebView had deprecated.